# sql query to get the unique entry for the group

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please help me with below query

```
Group1    Group 2    Group2_Value 
--------------------------------------
x          a            1
y          a            6
g          a            5
y          b            3
g          b            1
x          c            7
g          d            9
g          d            5
g          e            2
g          e            2
```

We have 3 values for Group1 x,y,g with g as highest priority  and x is lowest from the above record set I want to write a query or SP which will check that for each unique Group2 (a,b,c,d,e) return the row with the highest priority Group1  ,e.g.: for group 2 value "a" return the row 
with Group 1 value g and for group 2 value "c" return the one with "x" . Also if for group1 "g" we have 2 entries with different  Group2_Value then don't return any thing 
else return single unique row.

So the result should be like :

```
Group1   Group 2    Group2_Value    
--------------------------------------
g          a            5
g          b            1
x          c            7
g          e            2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This produces the desired output, hope it helps:

```
with xxx as (
    select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by group2 order by case group1 when 'g' then 1 when 'y' then 2 else 3 end ) as rn
    from #t
)
select group1, group2, max(group2_value)
from xxx
group by group1, group2
having count(*) = 1 
and max(rn) = 1

union all

select group1, group2, group2_value
from xxx
group by group1, group2, group2_value
having count(*) > 1
```

Probably not the most efficient way, though, but it's hard to tell without more information.

Comment: This was helpful to give me a hing of what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late post, I started this during a break and was pulled off.

First, lets create a test environment with your data.

```
-- Just playing
use tempdb;
go

-- Create a test table
create table test
(
  group1 varchar(4),
  group2 varchar(4),
  group2_val int
);
go

-- Add data
insert into [test] values
('x','a','1'),
('y','a','6'),
('g','a','5'),
('y','b','3'),
('g','b','1'),
('x','c','7'),
('g','d','9'),
('g','d','5'),
('g','e','2'),
('g','e','2');
go

-- Show data
select * from [test];
go
```

Second, I solved it with three common table expressions.  Each one built on top of each other.

```
-- Raw data with rank
with cteRawData
as
(
  select group2, group1, group2_val,
    rank() over 
    (
    partition by group2 order by
    case group1
      when 'g' then 1
      when 'y' then 2
      when 'x' then 3
      else 0
    end
    ) as drank
  from [test]
),
-- Get distinct topmost rank
cteRankData as
(
  select distinct group2, group1, group2_val
  from cteRawData where drank = 1
),
-- Find all singleton records
cteRankCount as
(
  select group2, group1
  from cteRankData 
  group by group2, group1
  having count(*) = 1
)
-- Return the results of a inner join
select a.group1, a.group2, a.group2_val
from 
cteRankData a inner join cteRankCount b
on a.group2 = b.group2 and a.group1 = b.group1
```

Last but not least, the expected results.

[image]